# Derivative of mean anomaly w.r.t true anomaly

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astrophysics, orbital-motion, astronomy

I am trying to work through the [workings in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.05718).

At one point (Eq. 10) the authors define the usual [mean anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly), $\beta$, the [true anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly), $\psi$, and the [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly) $u$ in the usual way:

$$ \beta = u - e \sin u \, \, ; \, \, \cos \psi = \frac{\cos u - e}{1 - e \cos u}$$

for eccentricity $e$.

Later on in the paper (Eq. 17), the authors declare than given the definitions presented for the various anomalies, than

$$ d \beta = \frac{(1-e^2)^{3/2}}{(1 + e \cos \psi)^2} d \psi$$

however I am struggling to reproduce the equation. Can anyone shed some light on how this is derived? Thanks

Comment: It is possible to write cos(u) in terms of cos(phi), then use the Pythagorean identity and substitute that in for sin(u) in the expression for beta (and substitute an arccos expression in for u); thus giving beta as a function of phi, which you can differentiate. It is also possible to obtain the differential of beta in terms of u & du from the first equation, obtain du in terms of phi & dphi from the second equation, and substitute. I started both approaches, and I admit I balked when I saw just how much tedious algebra is involved.

Comment: You have explicit, closed-form functions for the functions $\beta(u)$ and $\psi(u)$. Have you tried doing implicit differentiation on each of these and then eliminating $u$?

Comment: @electronpusher This was my problem too. I stick all into Mathematica and simplify and everything works out as it should. Happy to close the question unless advised otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating

$$\beta=u-e\sin{u}\tag{1}$$

gives

$$\frac{d\beta}{du}=1-e\cos{u}\tag{2}.$$

Differentiating

$$\psi=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos u-e}{1-e\cos u}\right)\tag{3}$$

gives

$$\frac{d\psi}{du}=\frac{(1-e^2)^{1/2}}{1-e\cos u}\tag{4}.$$

Dividing (2) by (4) gives

$$\frac{d\beta}{d\psi}=\frac{(1-e\cos u)^2}{(1-e^2)^{1/2}}\tag{5}.$$

Solving (3) for $\cos u$ gives

$$\cos u=\frac{\cos\psi+e}{1+e\cos\psi}\tag{6}$$

so

$$1-e\cos u=\frac{1-e^2}{1+e\cos\psi}\tag{7}.$$

Substituting this into (5) gives the desired result

$$\frac{d\beta}{d\psi}=\frac{(1-e^2)^{3/2}}{(1+e\cos\psi)^2}\tag{8}.$$

Fortunately all of these intermediate results are relatively simple expressions.